# Is it possible to get the VLC player layout, complete with media player buttons and a seekbar etc..?

Tags: android, exoplayer, libvlc, video-player, vlc-android

How to properly use the VLC video player. I want the video to play with a pause/resume button, Seekbar, and some default features displayed on the player. There is no official documentation. Could you please assist me in locating the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibVLC for Android is not like ExoPlayer. It **does not** come with a companion UI class or anything like that. Therefore, you have to build your very own UI for it.

A very good starting point would be to use ExoPlayer's very own UI and customize it to your need. Then you need to do your **own** bindings and listeners for the buttons.

LibVLC will be responsible for playing the video and anything related to the task, but it does not have anything that delegates user interaction with it. You have to do it manually.

If you face issues controlling and putting LibVLC to use, then you need to **thoroughly** inspect the code of VLC for Android. They made everything open-source so that's already a great thing. Check [VLC Android - Repository](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android)

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for your advice.
We'll try to use manual user interaction. 

Also, if there are any alternatives, please recommend one that can play all types of videos.